# Where to save Sublime text 3 snippet in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext3

I have this code snippet for C language:

**File name:** c.sublime-snippet
**File path:** /home/admin/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User

**Code:**

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

#include <stdio.h>

main(){
    ${1}
}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>init</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.c</scope>
</snippet>
```

After saving this file at the specified path(Check above) I still can't access the snippet with the specified tag `init`. I have tried this on windows and it worked fined. Any idea where to save the file c.sublime-snippet so it works on ubuntu ? Thank you

Comment: You can try this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BiceL9rgZZs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All user-generated files should be stored in the `Packages/User` directory. So, in your case, save it as `/home/admin/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/c.sublime-snippet`.

Also, it's generally a good idea to name snippets according to their `tabTrigger`, as you may eventually write multiple snippets dealing with C. So, you can rename it as `init.sublime-snippet` if you choose.

***EDIT***

Based on your edit indicating that the snippet was already saved in `Packages/User`, the only other likely reason for its failure is that the scope `source.c` was not actually in effect. You need to make sure to set your file's syntax to `C` in order for this scope to work - `C++` is `source.c++`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put the `User` directory. Actually the file is saved there :/

Comment: @Amir - see my edit above, and see if renaming the snippet works. The other thing to try is to make sure that your file's syntax is set to C. If it's C++ or something else the snippet won't work.

Comment: You are correct! I had to specified the syntax ctrl + shift + p > set syntax c. Can you edit your answer so I can mark it correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In **ubuntu 16.04** and sublime text 3, the snippets are stored at:

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User
```

The `.config` folder is hidden by default, so you won't be able to see it in your files application.

You can see it in terminal by doing `ls -a` or `ll`.